# Wordpress custom plugin developement

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to make a page in my plugin, but don't want it to appear in admin_menu, but just in my plugin page menu! I have a lot of pages, don't want them all to appear as sub menus! any ideas?

Comment: Try googling, that´s done before and then return with specific questions. Also please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`add_submenu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) and set `$parent_slug` to `null`:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        null,
        'My Custom Submenu Page',
        'My Custom Submenu Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-custom-submenu-page',
        'my_custom_submenu_page_callback',
    );
}
```